# Why doesn't my dictionary display its keys in Perl?

Tags: perl

```
my %dd;
$dd["foo"]="bar";
print keys %dd;
print %dd;
```

This is my code. This should display the keys of the dictionary `%dd` and the dictionary itself in the last two lines right? But it isn't! I've been breaking my head behind this since a couple of hours now but nothing helps.

Comment: you are confused with javascript hashes / objects, use {} instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is :

```
my %dd;
$dd{"foo"}="bar";
print keys %dd;
print %dd;
```

note: it is "{ }" instead of "[ ]"

Comment: Oh my GOD! I need some sleep. Thanks! :(

Comment: @ProgrammingNoob If you turn on [strict](https://metacpan.org/module/strict) and [warnings](https://metacpan.org/module/warnings) they will catch these sorts of errors for you.  `$dd["foo"]` is referencing `@dd` and not `%dd`. Also please ticky the check box to indicate Dheeraj answered your question.

Comment: @Schwern thanks for the tip about strict and warnings :) And I actually couldn't mark his answer accepted since it was too soon and you have to wait for some time after you ask the question before accepting an answer :)